# How do Dynamic Memory Network scale to large inputs?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, nlp

How do Dynamic Memory Network, for example from the paper [Ask Me Anything:
Dynamic Memory Networks for Natural Language Processing](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.07285.pdf), scale to large inputs? The paper states the following:

> In these cases, the input may be a sentence, a long story, a
>   movie review, a news article, or several Wikipedia articles.

Did anyone actually implement this network architecture to read an arbitrarily large corpus of text (say 250 Wikipedia articles)? The only example I could find online use rather small inputs (a few lines of text).

What is the bottleneck of using this type of network with large inputs? One solution I see is to encode paragraphs instead of sentences.